# ADF activity succeeded does not move on to the next activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Web activity that performs a GET operation to an endpoint. I have set it up to do something On Failure (which works just fine) and another set of action upon Success. But this last part gets skipped entirely even though the output of the Web action is Succeeded.
Here is shown the succeeded status and my config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GekWZ.png)

I tried removing and re-adding the On Success connector, but yielded no different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your flow, it would never proceed ahead:
[image]

Because as per your logic to proceed to the Set run time, Web activity 1 AND Web activity 2 should be success but that can never be the case since web activity 2 can be a success only if web activity 1 has failed thereby not proceeding further.

My blog explains how to handle this :
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score 0):

Both dependencies of `set runtime status` cannot end as succeeded. You need to use a combination of skipped/completed states: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-pipeline-failure-error-handling

Answer (score -1):

From the pipeline image  , I think it should move on with success .
Can you please cross check what is status code of web activity and is it returning something back ? Is the status code be 2xx ?  If I were you could have tried to check with the "Upon Completion" option and see it works .